# infant ticket and award flight

Tags: children

If I book a round-trip infant ticket for a child who is 18 months old on the moment of the trip but becomes 25 months old on the return leg, how fare is calculated? And what about award flights?

Comment: Which airline / award scheme in particular?

Comment: I don't know how to search for duplicates in the app, but this is an often discussed issue. typically, you cannot book a ticket for the child because she is not yet 2 years old, but you cannot book it without either because on the return trip he is over two years. you probably need to call them.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. As Aganju notes, this is a frequent question and as airline policies may vary, the only real answer may be to contact the airline for guidance. See *[Why is so difficult to fly across the 2-year old threshold with (some) airlines?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/108656)*. More distantly related is *[If I purchase a ticket with an age condition, at which point should the condition be satisfied?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36990)*

Comment: uhmm do I need to call them before or after the adult purchase ticket?

Answer (score 2):

The kid needs a valid ticket of her/his own for the return leg. You can either book a full round trip ticket for the entire flight or buy a separate one way for the return only.

Same rule applies regardless whether it's an award ticket or a cash ticket. Main difference: a one way award ticket tends to be half the miles/point of a round trip ticket whereas a one way cash ticket is typically more expensive than half the round trip fare and in some cases even more expensive than the round trip.

The safest approach is to get a round trip ticket for the kid. This way he/she can be on the same booking/reservation as you and if anything needs to be cancelled or changed, it all stays together. You also get a dedicated seat for the outbound leg, which makes travel more comfortable.

**EDIT**: Some online systems won't give you a separate ticket for a kid under 2: you may have to call the airline to get the round trip ticket booked or just make the kid older on the online booking system.

Comment: do you know any specific OTA or airline which let you book this online as one ticket?

Comment: I'm pretty sure most air airlines will. If you give them money, they will give you a ticket. You can book extra seats for yourself, for your pet or a car set, you can certainly book one for your infant. Here is what Emirates says on the topic: https://www.emirates.com/english/help/faq/193423/what-are-the-ticketing-rules-for-child-and-infant-passengers-on-emirates. I don't think anyone would make a fuzz if you just make your kid older during booking either.

Comment: Travelocity allows you to specify whether a kid under 2 will be "on lap" or "in a  seat". If you have two kids under 2 though, you can't say one is "on lap" while the other is "in a seat".